# How to prevent M-x package-install from editing my ~/.emacs file?

Tags: init-file, customize, custom-file

When I install packages with `M-x package-install`, it edits the `~/.emacs` file and adds the following content:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(package-selected-packages '(paredit slime)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
)
```

Is there a way to prevent `package-install` from editing my `~/.emacs` file. I write `~/.emacs` by hand and keep it neat, so it is quite disconcerting when `package-install` inserts this big blob of code in between. If `package-install` really needs to maintain this code somewhere, can I not make it put this code in another file that I can load into `~/.emacs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking that:

```lisp
(setq custom-file (concat user-emacs-directory "custom.el"))
(when (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (load custom-file))
```

Another way to get rid of the customization discussed here: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9rrhy8/emacsers_with_beautiful_initel_files_what_about/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file named `custom-file`, which you load from your init file, then Customize will save such customizations in that file.

I recommend doing that, to keep your hand-written Emacs-Lisp code separate (in your init file) from the file that Customize uses to write the code it uses to save your customizations.

I'm assuming that `package-install` does the same as Customize - it uses the file that's the value of variable `custom-file`, not your init file.  But I don't know that for a fact.  I don't see that mentioned in the doc string or in the manual.  If it doesn't then maybe it would be good to send an enhancement request for that: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Really, there's no good reason that either the package system or Customize should fiddle with your init file.  That's what `custom-file` is for: to tell Customize "Hands off my init file!"

Answer (score 0):

`custom-file` is all you need, as the other answers say, but you might also be interested in a more general approach.  You can "split" your customizations into as many files as you like, not just the one named by `custom-file`, if you use the package `initsplit`, available on MELPA.

From the package description:

> This file allows you to split Emacs customizations (set via M-x customize) into different files, based on the names of the
> variables.  It uses a regexp to match against each face and
> variable name, and associates with a file that the variable should be stored in.

It is then up to you to load each file, as in the answer @kadircancetin gave.

While the description mentions only `M-x customize`, the splitting takes place automatically whenever *any* customization is saved, including when `package-install` saves `package-selected-packages`.